# CodeIgniter - Loading View inside subfolder with Id

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, view, load

I'm working on a new project and I'm using subfolders with my Views and Controllers because it's going to be a fairly big application. My problem is I can not load a View with an Id. I'm getting "Unable to load requested file" error.

This will load my view, but because I don't have the Id needed in the URL I'm getting errors because some of the functions I have require it:

```
$this->load->view('administration/header');
$this->load->view('administration/add_vendor_location');
$this->load->view('administration/footer');
```

But when I try and include the Id like so:

```
$this->load->view('administration/header');
$this->load->view('administration/add_vendor_location/Id');
$this->load->view('administration/footer');
```

I'm getting the "Unable to load the requested file" error. I know I can use re-direct, but this is coming from a Form Validation and setting all the POST data and errors in sessions is very time consuming / annoying.

Hope this makes sense!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you provided, `views/administration/add_vendor_location/Id.php` must exist in order to load it.

If you're trying to pass a variable to the view, you would do so using an array in the secend parameter:

```
$this->load->view('administration/add_vendor_location', array(
    'id' => $id
));
```

See the [CI View documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Comment: Hopefully this will explain what I've done so far...

A user selects an account from a data-table, when viewing that account they click on a button "Add Location" that loads the following:

    administration/vendors/add_vendor_location/1

The function "add_vendor_location" loads a model based on the Id at the end of that URL. When I'm on that page and I submit the form and it fails validation, I need the view to carry across that Id again because I have a hidden field that looks for that Id at the end of the URL but it's not there.

Comment: Please help check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360697/link-to-view-inside-subfolder-does-not-display-correctly